# Jolt Transformation, replacing empty string in nested object with null

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

This is the sample input, there's various other key/values that I want to retain

```
[
    {
        // other data
        "employees": [{
            // other data
            "hireDate": ""
        }]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to set hireDate to null if its "" or " ", and keep all the other data in both objects, I've tried several different variations after looking hours googling and looking through documentation, but am unable to keep the other data key/values in each employee object there. Everything I try leaves the employees array empty.

```
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "*": {
            "*": "[&1].&",
            "employees": {
                "": null,
                " ": null,
                "*": {
                    "@": "&"
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value for a string with whitespace content such as `""`, `" "`, `"    "` etc., then you can use ***trim*** function along with a **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "employees": {
          "*": {
            "hD0": "=trim(@(1,hireDate))",
            "hD": "=size(@(1,hD0))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "employees": {
          "*": {
            "hD": {
              "0": "&3[&2].hireDate",
              "*": { "@2,hireDate": "&4[&3].hireDate" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```